# Obtaining the clean value of ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a controller I set the value:

```
ViewBag.incremento = 5;
```

I have the following View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Gestor.Models.PlanejVenda>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Índice";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Índice</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Criar novo planejamento de compra", "Create")
</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "PlanejVendas", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <p>
                Código: @Html.TextBox("search")
                <input type="submit" value="Procurar" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "PlanejVendas", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <p>
                Incremento Global: @Html.TextBox("search", new {@ViewBag.incremento })
                <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>

    Regula table here showing Ok
```

I was expecting that I would have the clean value 5 as set by the controler inside the textbox. But It shows: "{ incremento = 5 }" instead

[image: Showing more then the Viewbag]

How can I get the value of the ViewBag only, in the example just the number 5?

Answer (score 1):

You can try.

```
@Html.TextBox("search", (string)@ViewBag.incremento)
```

instead of

```
@Html.TextBox("search", new { @ViewBag.incremento })
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the `ViewBag` from the `TextBox`. `ViewBag` returns a collection of objects which you need to cast to the correct type.

For testing ignore `ViewBag` and use a constant.

What `new` is doing is to create an anonymous type instead of a value. Try

```
@Html.TextBox("search", "5")
```

If that works then cast the ViewBag item to a string as the answer from D-Shih suggests..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Incremento Global: @Html.TextBox("search", new { @value= ViewBag.incremento })`